# What is wrong with my xpath expression?

Tags: python, xpath

I want to extract all the links in td whose class is u-ctitle.

```
import os
import urllib
import lxml.html
down='http://v.163.com/special/opencourse/bianchengdaolun.html'
file=urllib.urlopen(down).read()
root=lxml.html.document_fromstring(file)
namelist=root.xpath('//td[@class="u-ctitle"]/a')
len(namelist)
```

The output is [],there are so many  td whose classis "u-ctitle" ,with firebug you ca get, why can't extract it?

[image]
My python version  is 2.7.9.
[image]

It is no use to change file into other name.

[image]

Comment: can you share the html from the webpage ?

Comment: Output couldn't be an empty list (`[]`) as `len()` should return integer... Also your `XPath` works fine (tried on `Python 3.5`, `requests` used instead of `urllib`- output `34`)..

Comment: Confirmed with Python 2.7.5, works and the list is _not_ empty. Are you sure you get `[]` as the output?

Comment: Also note that `file()` is built-in function in `Python 2.x`- you shouldn't use it as variable name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath is correct. The problem is unrelated.

If you examine HTML, you will see following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=GBK" />
```

And in this code:

```
file=urllib.urlopen(down).read()
root=lxml.html.document_fromstring(file)
```

`file` is actually a bytes sequence, so decoding from GBK-encoded bytes to  Unicode string is happening inside `document_fromstring` method.

The problem is, HTML encoding is not actually GBK and lxml decodes it incorrectly, leading to loss of data.

```
>>> file.decode('gbk')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "down.py", line 9, in <module>
    file.decode('gbk')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode bytes in position 7247-7248: illegal multibyte sequence
```

After some trial and error, we can find that actual encoding is [GB_18030](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_18030). To make script work, you need to decode bytes manually:

```
root=lxml.html.document_fromstring(file.decode('GB18030'))
```

Comment: Can you also explain why the output differs with different versions of Python/urllib/lxml? With Python 2.7.5/urllib 1.12/lxml 3.4.1 I can retrieve much more HTML than with Python 2.7.9/urllib 1.18/lxml 3.6.4. Thanks!

Comment: i want to know also.

Comment: I see the same result in py3.4.3/lxml3.7.2, py2.7.6/lxml3.7.2 and py2.7.6/lxml3.4.1. But anyway, I guess different versions of lxml *may* have slightly different handling of such situations.

Comment: Thanks anyway! I forgot to mention that the OS was also different: Mac OS X and Debian 7.